# Creating a new list from an existing one

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose we have a list containing four sub-lists like that

```
data = {
 {{1, -1}, {2, 5}, {3, 9}, {4, 2}}, 
 {{1, -4}, {2, 0}, {3, 11}, {4, -1}}, 
 {{1, 3}, {2, 2}, {3, 22}, {4, 1}}, 
 {{1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, -5}, {4, 7}}
 };
```

Now I want to create a new list, `data2`, containing the following

```
d1 = data[[1]];
d2 = data[[2]];
d3 = data[[3]];
d4 = data[[4]];
d11 = d1[[All, 1]];
d22 = d1[[All, 2]];
d33 = d2[[All, 2]];
d44 = d3[[All, 2]];
d55 = d4[[All, 2]];
data2 = Table[{d11[[i]], d22[[i]], d33[[i]], d44[[i]], d55[[i]]}, {i, 1, Length[d11]}]
```

which gives

> {{1, -1, -4, 3, 0}, {2, 5, 0, 2, 0}, {3, 9, 11, 22, -5}, {4, 2, -1, 1,
>      7}}

I am pretty sure that there must be a quicker and much more elegant way of obtaining the new list.

Any suggestions?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9):

In:

```
m = Map[Last, data, {2}];
v = First /@ First@data;
Thread[Prepend[m, v]]
```

Out:

```
{{1, -1, -4, 3, 0}, {2, 5, 0, 2, 0}, {3, 9, 11, 22, -5}, {4, 2, -1, 1,
   7}}
```

Comment: Very nice and quick!

Answer (score 8):

```
Transpose[Prepend[data[[All, All, 2]], data[[1, All, 1]]]]
```

or

```
Flatten[{{data[[1, All, 1]]}, data[[All, All, 2]]}, {{3}, {1, 2}}]
```

or

```
Drop[Flatten[data, {{2}, {1, 3}}], {}, {3, -2, 2}]
```

Comment: Nice! Let's wait for a while to see if someone else has anything else to suggest.

Comment: In your last one you could flatten levels 1 and 3 the other way and so put all the dropped elements together `Flatten[data, {{2}, {3, 1}}][[All, 4 ;;]]`

Answer (score 6):

here you are

```
l1 = Length@data;
l2 = First[Length /@ data];
Table[d = Table[Join[data[[i]][[j]]], {i, 1, l1}];
Drop[Join[First /@ d, Last /@ d], l1 - 1], {j, 1, l2}]
```

> {{1, -1, -4, 3, 0}, {2, 5, 0, 2, 0}, {3, 9, 11, 22, -5}, {4, 2, -1, 1,
>      7}}

Comment: It works only when four sub-lists are present. I tested it in a case with 1000 lists and it failed.

Comment: I think you are wrong. I never used the number 4. I used length@data

Comment: Take for example the list `data = {
   {{1, -1}, {2, 5}, {3, 9}, {4, 2}, {5, 1}}, {{1, -4}, {2, 0}, {3, 
     11}, {4, -1}, {5, 1}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 2}, {3, 22}, {4, 1}, {5, 
     1}}, {{1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, -5}, {4, 7}, {5, 1}}
   };` The method proposed buy Coolwater gives the correct answer, while yours is not correct.

Comment: I fixed it... it was working for nxn

Comment: Now it works fine!

Comment: yes, but coolwater's solution is way better ;-)

Answer (score 6):

```
Join[{#[[1]]}, #2] & @@@ Transpose[data, {3, 1, 2}]
```

> {{1, -1, -4, 3, 0}, {2, 5, 0, 2, 0}, {3, 9, 11, 22, -5}, {4, 2, -1, 1, 7}}

Answer (score 5):

```
Join[#[[1]], #[[2 ;;, 2]]] & /@ (Transpose@data)
```

> {{1, -1, -4, 3, 0}, {2, 5, 0, 2, 0}, {3, 9, 11, 22, -5}, {4, 2, -1, 1,
>      7}}

Answer (score 4):

I found this line of thought most intuitive:

```
Transpose[Join[data[[{1}, ;; , 1]], data[[;; , ;; , 2]]]]
```

If you would call all your pairs `{x,y}` then this takes all y`s and prepends a single x. This is already the transposed version of what you want.

It is very similar to the first option provided by coolwater, but perhaps more people intuitively understand `Join` than `Prepend`.

Answer (score 3):

```
Drop[#, {3, 8, 2}] & /@ Partition[Flatten[Transpose@data], 8]
```